# Does MC-DC2 release cable work with Nikon D750?

Tags: nikon, remote, compatibility

I see confusing views about the Nikon MC-DC2 remote release cord. Some people say it is compatible with the D750, and some say it is not. I am not sure if any one here has successfully used MC-DC2 with their Nikon D750?

I recently upgraded my camera from D80 to D750 and was surprised to find that I can't use the MC-DC1 for my long exposure shots. I am leaving on a trip on Thursday, and need a solution quickly that will work with the Nikon D750. I have to buy this ASAP so that it can be delivered before Thursday.

Or, if there are any other options that you have tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Nikon USA](http://www.nikonusa.com/en/Nikon-Products/Product/Remote-Cords/MC-DC2-Remote-Release-Cord-%281-meter%29.html) lists the MC-DC2 release cable as compatible with the D750. Sellers that don't include the D750 in the list of cameras that are compatible with the MC-DC2 probably created the listing before the D750 was introduced.

An example: B&H doesn't include the D750 in the list of compatible cameras at the [product information page](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/bnh/controller/home?O=&sku=580879&gclid=CLjCtKrbl8UCFUlo7AodbSMAZw&Q=&is=REG&A=details). But if you click on the *Q&A* tab on that page and scroll down to the fourth question you see that a staff member at B&H has recently verified that it is compatible with the D750.

Answer (score 0):

I have the mc-dc2 and it works just fine with my d-750 !!

Comment: Does it work with long exposures?